# BULK INSERT Data from file but ignore the first occurence of field terminator

Tags: sql-server, insert, bulkcopy

I have a file that has data arranged in the following style:

```
    1    1    0.5102    0.4898    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
    1    2    0.3114    0.6886    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
```

I need to load this into a table on MS-SQL and process it. I am using the BULK INSERT statement with the following settings

```
FIELDTERMINATOR = '    '
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
```

But what happens is that I end up with a table having this content (NOTE: I made all columns `VARCHAR` to see how the data is getting imported):

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL3    COL5    COL6    COL7
NULL    1       1       0.5102  0.4898  0.0000  0.0000    0.0000
NULL    1       2       0.3114  0.6886  0.0000  0.0000    0.0000
```

Essentially, there is a '    '(four spaces) before the first column of data. But BULK IMPORT assumes that the first column is `NULL` and offsets the data by a column.

Now, my question - is it possible to obviate this issue? Can we instruct BULK INSERT to ignore the first occurrence of the `FIELD TERMINATOR`? I cannot change the input file as it is used by some other parts of the process.

Comment: Did you try adding the spaces to the end of the row terminator? (If this works, make sure you still get the last row.)

Comment: Nice trick. But now all rows of data except the first row looks good... Any way to resolve that?

Comment: Ahhh, the files don't have a header row? (I may have misread.)

Comment: See [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22763/2718) -- I believe this can be done using a format file.

Answer (score 1):

If the amount of data is small enough or you can otherwise afford to spend a bit more resources on the operation, there are ways around this. Most of the scenarios where I've done bulk inserts required additional data manipulation in any case, so I usually just insert the bulk data to a specially created bulk insert table, and then manipulate and transfer the data to the real table from there. Makes tasks such as this one a lot easier. But of course there's an increased overhead from handling the same data twice.